# Laravel Query Builder result using join() query

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

The following query works fine, but the problem is that it gives the id of the events table instead of tasks table id in the output result.

```php
Task::join('events', function ($join) {
    $join->on('events.task_id', '=', 'tasks.id')
        ->where('events.event_type', '=', 'Task')
        ->where('events.task_stage', '!=', 'assigned');
})->select('tasks.*')
->get();
```

Comment: this one duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, one should work

```
->select('*', 'tasks.id as taskID')->get();
```

This is because maybe both tasks and events table have id field. So u need to use a separate query to specify the id.

Answer (score 2):

try this one

**use mysql alias here**

```
Task::join('events', function ($join) {
        $join->on('events.task_id', '=', 'tasks.id')
            ->where('events.event_type', '=', 'Task')
            ->where('events.task_stage', '!=', 'assigned');
 })->select('tasks.*','tasks.id as taskId')->get();
```