# How can I give two different types of users the same functionality in Laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel, database-migration

I want to give two different types of users the ability to create the same event, however the event needs a user_id, which the two different types of users could share.

I am making an application in Laravel where two different types of users, a Player and a Vendor, can each make an event.

Player

```
Schema::create('players', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->integer('player_id_type')->default('1');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('player_id');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Vendor

```
Schema::create('vendors', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('store name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

event

```
Schema::create('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('user_id');
            $table->string('name')
        });
```

The problem is that a Player and Vendor could both have the id = 1. Also, when creating the event I would not know whether to look for a player with that id or a vendor.

Please over some suggestions on how I could either solve this or implement it differently.

Thank you.

Comment: I would probably create one single "users" table with all the users and just have a column stating what type of user it is.

Comment: "The problem is that a Player and Vendor could both have the id = 1". To differentiate which of id to use either Vendor or Player, you can use alias in your query statement like: select("*","playertable.id as pID, vendortable.id as vID")

Comment: Check this post out. I think you can get something out of it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56642293/laravel-query-builder-result-using-join-query/56642445#56642445

Answer (score 0):

there is conflict, that you have two table of same primary key when retriving the 'event' entity than which table refers user_id ? so you can add third table called user and than relate with event so that the conflict reduces

Comment: Adding another table not necessary here since using sql alias will solve the problem.